# Java Floating point modulo error

Tags: java

```
    float a = (float) 3.32 ; 
    float b = (float) 4.32 ; 
    System.out.println(b%a);
```

output on my machine is 1.0000002

Why ?

Comment: Floating point types are imprecise by their nature. Small errors like this are inevitable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: See [What every programmer should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First how to declare a float value as a variable?

```
float val=3.23f;
```

About your result.
   It is a typical nature of `float` .

How to get correct answer? try this way

```
 BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("3.32") ;
 BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("4.32") ;
 System.out.println(b.divideAndRemainder(a)[1]); // 1st element is remainder
```

Out put:

```
 1
```

You may need to read about [divideAndRemainder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

Comment: @downvoter, can't see your comment.

Comment: i have upvoted for feng shui :)